# how to write a java method that read strings seperated by commas

Tags: java

i intend to read lines of numbers separated by comma's example below

> 08090417241, 080904152335, 080998766231, 080913456786, 08035467901,
>   08070415243, 080675534387, 080355525288, 080345887698, 0809966355343, ...

to the last number.

The original code I used in my program is this

```
 String file1 = FileArea6.getText();
```

This gives an error when I try to read the numbers with the above example. But when the numbers are arranged in the order below, it's read perfectly.

```
08035467901
08035474477
08024444448
08012233333
09033222333.......
```

What is the right way to read using the first example, i.e. separated by comma's?

Comment: What error are you getting? Could you please provide more info

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `str.split(',')`

```
List<String> nums = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

or

```
List<String> nums = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
```

or

```
String[] nums = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following simple code snippet should work.

```
            try {
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input file"));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] strArray = line.split(",");
                    for (String str : strArray) {
                        System.out.println( str.trim());

                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] separateByComma(String s){
    String[] tmp = s.split(",");
    int n = 0, i=0;

    while(i<tmp.length){
        if(check(tmp[i])) tmp[n++] = tmp[i]; 
        i++;
    }       
    if(n==0) return null;

    String[] res = new String[n];

    while(--n >= 0) res[n] = tmp[n];
    return res;
}

/*
 * Your check function
 * You can filter anything
 */
boolean check(String s){
    if(s==null || s.length()<1) return false;
    return true;
}
```